# How do I get a value out of ElasticSearch using a Kibana Watcher

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Suppose that I have a dictionary of {"check_result": {"services": ['a','b','c'], "health": "red"}}. I send a Slack Notification when the number of messages with "health":"red" exceed 1 per minute using payload.hits.total. How do I pass the value in the key "services" to the Slack Message?

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have tried using a script to pass the services into the ctx.payload but it still can't access the data.